# r animation, parametric curve

Tags: r

I am using the animation package to plot the parametric curve for
$x=sin(t)$ and $y=sin(t)^2$ along with the circle tracing the curve using the following code:

```
require(animation)
x <- seq(-1,1,length=20)
y <- x^2
plot(x,y,type="l")
library(animation)
ani.record(reset=TRUE)
t <- seq(0,4*pi,by=pi/30)
for (i in 1:length(t)) {
    points(sin(t[i]),sin(t[i])^2,pch=19,cex=2)
    ani.record()
    plot(x,y,type="l")  # I have a question in this line
 }
 ani.replay()
```

It works (please copy and paste this code) but recording takes quite a time. This is a simple curve, but should I have wanted to
do the complicated one, it will take too much time to finish recording the animation. 
One thing I may improve upon this is not to use the 2nd plot function to redraw the parobola to get rid of the circle appear in the previous plot.
Is there anything I can make it better?

Answer (score 2):

The base R package `grDevices` has two functions that allows for the saving and playback of a plot, designed for situations like this:

- `recordPlot()`
- `replayPlot()`

A somewhat subjective test on my machine seems to indicate that it is faster than replotting the entire plot:

```
require(animation)
x <- seq(-1,1,length=20)
y <- x^2
plot(x,y,type="l")
oopts <- ani.opts(interval=0.25)
p <- recordPlot()   # <== Record plot here =============
ani.record(reset=TRUE)
t <- seq(0,4*pi,by=pi/30)

for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  replayPlot(p)     # <== Replay plot here =============
  points(sin(t[i]),sin(t[i])^2,pch=19,cex=2)
}
ani.replay()
```

Comment: Just a note: I think `recordPlot` is from `grDevices`, otherwise: +1 :)

Comment: @daroczig Thank you for the correction. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I honestly don't know whether this makes it faster. Is there any justification that it should make it faster?

Comment: I think you forgot `ani.record()` inside the loop.

Comment: @Ikuyasu I didn't forget to add `ani.record()` - I removed it since it's not necessary to illustrate the point. As I said - subjectively I think it's faster, but I didn't perform a detailed test.