# R animation: Adding letters one by one on a plot

Tags: r, plot

Now I have a plot (regular plot), and I'm trying to add four letters "A", "B", "C", "D" one by one onto the plot. The coordinates for the four letters are, say, (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1). Moreover I wish I could control the speed of adding points, for example, add "A" at time = 1, "B" at time = 2, "C" at time = 4 and "D" at time = 8.

Any help would be so appreciated!

Jiayu

Comment: Take a look at the [`animation` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/index.html) (its `animation` function), and `?text`.

Comment: You should post some code for this to show us what've you done so far.

Comment: there are answers here on so that show all the components of this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919390/r-animation-parametric-curve and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453695/adding-text-to-a-plot